# How to make the margin between element same on orientation?

Tags: android, html, ios, iphone, media-queries

whenever the orientation of the phone is portrait the margin between the main div and the header is 20px. I did set it via media query like:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 760px) and (min-device-width: 320px){col-main{margin-top:20px;}}
```

I suppose that this is for the portrait view since it is like normal view. Then I added the media query for the landscape view:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 760px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation : landscape){col-main{margin-top:40px;}}
```

whenever I gone from portrait to landscape in the mobile browser is ok but when it came from the landscape to portrait the `margin-top:40px` is still being read not the `margin-top:20px`.

what should I do with it?

Comment: Why iOS Tagged?

Comment: Try like: 

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* Styles for Landscape screen */
}

maby the previous rule over writing it

Comment: @Mr.UB cause it is same with safari browser on iOS

Comment: @LukeRobertson I only intend it for mobile browser

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 @media only screen and (max-device-width: 760px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait)
    {col-main{margin-top:20px;}}
```

Comment: some how it works but it has a fall down. @SanjeetMistry